# While n > 1. Decrease n by 1 on each iteration

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm working on some hackerrank problems and I've looked at a couple of ways to take this input and loop through it.

What is be best alternative to trying to decrease n on each iteration as below (as this doesn't seem to be possible).

```
first_n = int(raw_input())

def findPercentage(n):
    if n > 1:
        studentinfo = raw_input()
        return studentinfo
        n = n - 1

result = findPercentage(first_n)
print result
```

As I'm knew to this, I understand that my logic might be flawed.
The input is passed as stdin with the first line listing the total number of lines to follow. I will want to perform a single operation on every line after the first line with the exception of the last line where I'd look to perform a different operation.

Comment: The `return` statement is before the decrement. It should be after. And yes, your logic here is wrong. This will just take `studentinfo` input and return if `first_n` is greater than 1. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I've no idea what you're trying to achieve. There's no while loop and `n = n - 1` coming after `return student info` will **never** execute.

Comment: The problem I am working on is [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/finding-the-percentage) . I'm not looking for the answer but rather a better way that I can approach it. First, I want to grab the input into useful variables or maybe a list of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n= int(input())

studentinfo= {}

for i in range(n):
    inputs= raw_input().split(" ")
    studentinfo[inputs[0]]= inputs[1:];
```

This will create a dictionary `studentinfo` with names as key and list of marks as value.

Comment: It took me a long time but I got it thanks to this (while avoiding the suggested solution until after) - http://pastebin.com/UEZWXzA1

Answer (score 0):

The first line gives you the number of students N:

```
n = int(raw_input())
```

Then you want to loop through your function N number of times:

`for i in range(n):
      studentinfo = raw_input().split(" ")
      print(studentinfo[0])`

This will create a `list` called `studentinfo`, and this will print the student's name. See where you can go from there.

Comment: Thanks for this - while I am aware of a working efficient solution in the comments on that site - I've ignored it. The First test to pass but not the second. This will help for now... I'll keep hacking away.